# How do I input data attribute values with multiple classes to a div after button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

What I'm trying to achieve is to append a paragraph tag with an added text value, depending on the choice the user make, based on a data attribute.

However, the data attribute is within the same class and there is a total of 12 of these classes.

How do I differentiate the multiple values on button click?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aahlfeeyann/pen/dzejOg

```
<div class="container q1">
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1A">1A</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1B">1B</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1C">1C</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1D">1D</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container q2">
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2A">2A</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2B">2B</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2C">2C</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2D">2D</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container q3">
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3A">3A</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3B">3B</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3C">3C</button></div>
    <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3D">3D</button></div>
</div>

// Message to Preview
var buttonMessage = $('.btn-card').data('messages');
$('.btn-card').click(function(){
    console.log(buttonMessage);
    $('#messageOne').append(buttonMessage);
})
```

Comment: not sure I fully understand but if you want to append something to the container you are in you can use `$(this).closest(classname)` or if it is for where you clicked on `$(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your variable to inside the `click` function, and use `$(this)` to get the data attribute of the clicked element.

```js
$('.btn-card').click(function() {
  var buttonMessage = $(this).data('messages');
  console.log(buttonMessage);
  $('#messageOne').append(buttonMessage);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container q1">
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1A">1A</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1B">1B</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1C">1C</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="1D">1D</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container q2">
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2A">2A</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2B">2B</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2C">2C</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="2D">2D</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container q3">
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3A">3A</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3B">3B</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3C">3C</button></div>
  <div class="row"><button class="btn btn-card" data-messages="3D">3D</button></div>
</div>
```